# Invariant subspace of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The matrix of a linear transformation $A$ is given below. Find all its invariant subspaces.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

I found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and I suppose they form invariant subspaces. Are there any other invariant subspaces? And what's the general approach to tackling this problem?

Comment: it has complex spectrum https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B0%2C0%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D

Comment: You are working over which field?

Comment: It isn't stated in the task, I suppose it's over the field of real numbers

Comment: In that case there’s no eigenspace that corresponds to the complex eigenvalues, so you’ll need to do a bit more work to find the invariant subspaces.

Comment: The only proper and non-trivial invariant subspaces (over $\Bbb R$) are the $xz$ plane and the $y$-axis.